# how to use KeepAliveCache get(url,object)

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I have an old application that seems to be written in java 1.4 or 1.3. and I am migrating it to 1.7. The issue is that it is using `KeepAliveCache`'s `get(URL)` method inthe old implementation, while the new signature is `get(URL, Object)`.

Can someone explain me how to use this method? Can I do `get(URL, URL)`?

Comment: What is "kac"? Certainly not an instance of HttpURLConnection, none of the method signatures you provided exists in any Java version.

Comment: My bad :c KeepAliveCache, i am not thinking straight right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KeepAliveCache` is a `sun.*` class that shouldn't have been used in the first place, for exactly the reason you have encountered: it is an implementation-private class whose API is subject to change without notice.

Just remove it and use what's provided in `java.net`. It does connection pooling and all that for you automatically. No need to peer under the hood. You'll improve code quality and probably fix bugs too.

Comment: @user2004685 Don’t ‘correct’ my punctuation thanks. I know what I’m doing.